# Requiring multiple modules in one project/gem

Tags: ruby

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Project
├── lib
│   ├── project.rb
│   └── thor_commands
│       ├── cli_starter.rb
│       ├── command1.rb
│       └── command2.rb
└── runme
```

**runme**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative 'lib/project.rb'
```

**project.rb:**

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/thor_commands/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

**cli_starter.rb**

```
require_relative command1.rb  # Why do I need these
require_relative command2.rb  #

module MyThorCLI
  class Base < Thor
    Command1 ...
  end
end
```

If I run something like `runme cmd1` without `require_relative command1` and `require_relative command2` in `cli_starter.rb`, I get an error: `uninitialized constant MyThorCLI::Base::Command1`.

I'm trying to understand why I need to `require_relative command1` and `require_relative command2` although everything were already required in `project.rb`.

It looks to me that modules and classes in those modules should be loaded during run time, but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cli_starter.rb` is referencing `Command1` at require time, before the other files have been loaded: there's no separate resolution step.

The additional `require_relative` calls ensure those files are loaded first, so their constants are available while `cli_starter.rb` is getting loaded.

The various forms of `require` are essentially equivalent to inserting the content of the file at that point in the code (if it hasn't already been required).

So (depending on the order `Dir[]` finds the files from your glob), the overall failing execution looks something like:

```
module MyThorCLI
  class Base < Thor
    Command1 ...
  end
end

class Command1
end
```

With no separate resolution step, this fails when it hits the `Command1` reference, because the class definition hasn't been encountered yet -- it's several lines below.

---

Adding those requires is a perfectly reasonable solution to the problem. The potentially tricker approach is to change the contents of `cli_starter.rb` so it doesn't reference the other constants until later (by putting those references inside later-called methods, instead of directly inside the class body). Whether that's feasible depends on what your class body is doing with them.

```
class Base ..
  @@first_command = Command1 # this reference is evaluated when it's encountered
  def first_command
    @@first_command
  end

# -->

class Base ..
  def first_command
    Command1 # this one is evaluated when the method is called
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "later called methods" and "require time".  Is there a bottom-up resolution of symbols during runtime?  I guess I always assumed all was loaded into the main `$.` scope and things were executed based on that?

Comment: I expanded the explanation in the answer, does that help? (One shouldn't actually use class variables, incidentally -- that was just an easy super-short example of how one might encounter a deferrable reference.)